# Can "il"-only words be used with subject being "on"?

Tags: vocabulaire

I know that *falloir* has only one subject case that is 3rd-person singular (*il*) and it's only valid to say *il faut* and *il fallait*. An object can also be supplied like *il me faut* and *il nous faut*.

But is it grammatically correct to say *on me faut* or *on m'a fallu*? They sound OK to me. Does this apply to other *il*-only verbs like *pleuvoir* or *s'agir*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short and simple: no. It is incorrect.

Such verbs are only used with the impersonal "il" (the only exception may be *pleuvoir* when used in a figurative way, eg *les coups pleuvent*).

Comment: *on ne m'a faut pas le dire...*

Comment: @iBug May be what you have in mind is "on ne doit pas me le dire"?

Comment: If you are keen on using *on* and express an obligation, you can indeed use *on doit* for *il faut*, eg *il faut partir* is more or the less the same as *on doit partir*

Comment: @Gred Yeah I know *devoir* is an alternative, but the question is about *il*-only words and *falloir* is just an example.

Comment: Still "les coups pleuvent" is 3rd person... As a side note, as your answer got accepted I think it would be good to actually name "such verbs" (les verbes défectifs) and maybe provide a reference...

Comment: What should I say with *on* + *devoir* for the equivalent of *il **me** faut* (with an object)? Or should I not use *on* here but just *je dois*?

Comment: *On doit* will either be an equivalent of *il faut*, or of *nous devons* (in spoken French, *on* is very often used for *nous*). If you want to use the 1st person singular with *devoir*, you should indeed say *je dois*. Note that *il me faut* + verb is grammatically perfect, but is much more formal or would barely used in normal, everyday conversations. You would not say for instance *il me faut aller aux toilettes* but *je dois aller aller aux toilettes*.